# Как импортировать .pyc модуль в Python?

Tags: python, модули

Как импортировать модуль с расширением .pyc?
Он называется tmodule.cpython-36.pyc.
Мне важно не убирать часть .cpython-36, чтобы имя модуля осталось прежним.
Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 4):

Если вы хотите импортировать модуль `foo` из `.pyc` файла, не имея `foo.py` файла, то файл должен называться `foo.pyc` и лежать в той же директории, где `foo.py` лежал бы. Посмотрите [на диаграмму](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/#flow-chart):

[image: import flow chart]